# Как вставить данные в таблицу используя данные другого столбца?

Tags: sql

Есть таблица video, столбцы VID и embed, подскажите как вставить данные, что-то вроде

```
UPDATE video set embed = '<iframe width="720" height="400" id="videoplayer" src="http://site/embed/(**VID**)" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>'
```

Comment: `UPDATE video set embed = '<iframe width="720" height="400" id="videoplayer" src="http://site/embed/'||vid||'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>'`

Comment: Он так и прописывает http://site/embed/'||vid||' без вставки данных VID

Comment: Объясните условие подробнее. Нужна вставка данных или обновление? В каких столбцах какие данные имеются на момент обновления/вставки?

Comment: В VID данные, embed пустой, в embed вставить '<iframe width="720" height="400" id="videoplayer" src="http://site/embed/'VID'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>' используя данные столбца VID

Comment: Какая у вас БД? Попробуйте так `UPDATE video set embed = concat(concat('<iframe width="720" height="400" id="videoplayer" src="http://site/embed/', vid), '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>')`